# Problem with Transparency/Mix Shader: shadow on the contact zone stays

Tags: animation, transparency, shadows

Hello Blender community!

I have a problem during a 3D animation: I am using "Transparent BSDF" and "Mix Shader" to make some components of my assembly disappear.

[image]

Anyway when they are transparent, they are still casting on the contact zone their perimeter shadow, as you can see in the picture below with the aluminum profiles. I have tried to increased the light path bounces to the maximum but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Eevee? This happens when objects are intersecting on their faces(it basically casts shadows even while invisible... my always used solution is to move it by very little value like 0,001 by collision axis and it always fixes problem. If you use Eevee you should go to material settings and change Blend and Shadow modes

Comment: With this version of the Principled shader you can skip the mix and transparency and just use the alpha setting on the principled.  Use zero when you want it invisible and 1 when you want it visible.  But you still need to check for surface contact as @MikoCG said above.

Comment: @MikoCG I am using Cycles, but that is very interesting...I have not thought about it, Thanks a lot!